# Impossible to write or edit posts on SO using `begin snippet`

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, quality-filter, warning-message

Attempting to write or update a Stack Overflow post that uses the `begin snippet` directive seems to be impossible currently.

For example, attempt to edit any answer in this post, and it will be impossible:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717402/3708426

This is the error message you get, and it's not possible to get the post into a formatting SO will accept.

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a SO bug?

Comment: I was able to edit and answer posts on that question (all which contained the "begin snippet" directive) - is it just [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717402/3708426) particular answer that you're facing the editing issue with, and no other answers?

Comment: There's a lot of "special" characters in that post.

Comment: > is it just this particular answer that you're facing the editing issue with, and no other answers?

Yes, that is indeed the one